# Python: how to change a module's path when creating a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

We have a project in our company, developed in Python. Internally, we use `import our_cool_module`. We'd like to open source it, but change the import path to `import our_cool_company.our_cool_module`. How can we do this without making any changes to the code or to the actual directories it's in? (using Python 3 if its relevant)

Comment: To have this import path the package has to be in `our_cool_company/our_cool_module` and when you want to add a `setup.py` you two entries in `packages`. If this is just to "promote" your company and the parent package has not relevant functionality, then it might not be a good idea. BTW if I'd use it as an Open Source package that would the first thing I'd change back.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not do this. This is against good practices. There is nothing cool about doing this. And if you do this, a lot of people who do not know your company ahead of time will not use the module.

```
# Can you imagine if I had to do this to install Django?
pip install microsoft
```

If it is a good useful module, leave it as such. Your company will eventually be known and get the credit for it. A good example is *React*, the *Javascript* library developped by *Facebook*. Nowhere in the code do you see that they developped it. But it's good enough that everybody knows.

Note: no, *Microsoft* did not develop *Django*.